# React Confirm Alert library showing "Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-18

I'm trying to use the **[react-confirm-alert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-confirm-alert)** library for a **confirmation dialog**. But it's giving me a warning when the confirmation pop-up is opening for the react version upgrade. "**Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17**." Is there any way to get rid of the warning? Or is there any good alternative library that I can use for a confirmation dialog?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
```

then

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

Probably your answer must be:

Try this in your index file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
        <App />
        );
```

This works in latest react version.